# Debris dropped on exhaust fan from top by roofer

Tags: bathroom, exhaust-fan, interference

My roofer's accidentally dropped debris onto the fan part of my bathroom exhaust fan. What is the simplest way to remove the debris without taking apart the whole fan?

[image: bathroom exhaust fan]

Comment: simplest way: refuse the pay the roofers until they remedy this.

Comment: Is the area above the fan accessible from your attic (if you have one)?  If so, it might be easiest to have your roofer (who dropped the debris) to into your attic, disconnect the vent pipe from the fan, and remove the debris.  Depending on how it's attached and constructed, the vent pipe might need some repairs afterwards, but that should be the responsibility of the roofer to mitigate problems caused by them.

Comment: I'm curious what the actual problem is.  The debris dented the fan casing and it won't run now?  Because the fan itself should be in a sealed(ish) box.

Answer (score 3):

Those fans are designed to be easily removable.   Somewhere there is a screw or spring latch.

You can even see in this replacement fan from Amazon, the power cord has a plug on it.

[https://www.amazon.com/Broan-Nutone-S-97016621-QTR070-QTR080/dp/B01N7UF4ZH](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N7UF4ZH)

[image]

Comment: Good answer. While the fan is out is a good time to clean the unit and oil the bushings so the motor will last for a while longer and remain quiet. These are simple induction motors that come apart easily and the bushings are usually permeable bronze so you can put 3in1 'motor' type oil (for electric motor bushings) into the outside fabric.

Comment: @RGHughes don't say "motor * oil" lest someone confuse it with car engine oil.  3in1 and "sewiing machine oil" are good phrases.

Comment: @Griggie - Good point, though the bottle literally says 'motor' oil. I should have been clear that it is 3in1 made or electric motors and labelled as such.